# Как четные столбцы матрицы инициализировать в обратном порядке?

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

const int N1 = 10, // Максимальны размер строк
          M1 = 10; // Максимальный размер столбцов

int a[N1][M1], //матрица
    i, j, // номер строки и столбца
    n, m; // текущий размер матрицы

cout << "Введите количество строк и столбцов массива" << endl;

cin >> n >> m;

int q = n;
int k = 0;

for (j = 1; j <= m; j++)
{
    if (j % 2 == 0)
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            
            
            
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            a[i][j] = i;
        }
    }
    
    
}

cout << "Полученная матрица" << endl;

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
    {
        cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        
    }  
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: По моему вы пытаетесь инициализировать в обратном порядке, а не выводить

Comment: Поправил название, спасибо

Comment: индексация в массивах `0..n-1` : то есть нужно исправить `a[i-1][j-1]`

Comment: в обратном порядке это по времени или по значению? Не могу догадаться какими числами надо его забить.

Comment: В обратном порядке по значению, т.е первый столбец с 1 до n, четный столбец c n до 1

Comment: Крайне непонятно что это и как это использовать, объясните пожалуйста

Comment: Элемент с индексом `i` должен иметь значение `n+1-i`. Это приводит например при `i=1` к числу `n`, а при `i=n` к единице.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятней

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    #include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

const int N1 = 10, // Максимальны размер строк
          M1 = 10; // Максимальный размер столбцов

int a[N1][M1], //матрица
    i, j, // номер строки и столбца
    n, m; // текущий размер матрицы

cout << "Введите количество строк и столбцов массива" << endl;

cin >> n >> m;

int k = n;
int b = 0;

for (j = 1; j <= m; j++)
{
    if (j % 2 == 0)
    {
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                a[i][j] = (n + 1) - i;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                a[i][j] = i;
            }
        }
        
        
    }

    cout << "Полученная матрица" << endl;

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
    {
        cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        
    }  
    cout << endl;
}

}
```

Comment: Вы забыли про индексацию массивов, что я вам говорил : `a[i-1][j-1] = n+1-i;`

Answer (score -1):

Не уверен, что правильно понял ваши пожелания, но все же:

```
for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)         
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        //сами подумайте чем хотите инициализировать
        if (j % 2 == 0)
            a[i - 1][j] = i;                

        else
            a[n - i][j] =  i;
    }
```

Comment: Только  я поправлю заголовок  _ заставлять  тут  ничего не нужно, все выполнится так, как вы напишете.

Comment: Раз такая жара, продолжим? `a [ i - 1 + ( n - i - i + 1 ) * ( j % 2 ) ] [ j ] = i ;`