# Переворот нечетных столбцов матрицы

Tags: c++

Никак не могу додумать как исправить

```
void Quest(int n, int n2) {

int** matrix = new int* [n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    matrix[i] = new int[n2];


for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
    {
        matrix[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
    }
   
}

cout << endl;

//тут нужно подправить 
for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (matrix[i][j] % 2 == 1) {

            int tmp = matrix[i][j];
            matrix[i][j] = matrix[n - 1 - i][j];
            matrix[n - 1 - i][j] = tmp;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
//-------------------


cout << "Полученная матрица" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1208083/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b5

Comment: Нечётные столбцы – столбцы с нечётным номером? Поворот – запись в обратном порядке?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен переворот нечетных столбцов. Вы проверяете элемент матрицы, а не столбец
`matrix[i][j]` это элемент матрицы, нужно проверить столбцы

```
if(matrix[i]%2==1)
{
int tmp = matrix[i][j];
matrix[i][j] = matrix[n - 1 - i][j];
matrix[n - 1 - i][j] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: ошибка на строке if(matrix[i]%2==1) выражение должно относиться к целочисленному типу или типу перечисления без области видимости